# On which system user my simple daemon on Linux should run as default for best compatibility?

Tags: linux, daemon, convention

I'm developing a simple Linux network daemon that runs as `root`, `chroot()` to the data files directory and drop `root` privileges. I like the "convention over configuration" approach, and even that my software has a configuration to set which user and group it will use, I want to use a sensible default.

Which default should I use? User `nobody` and group `nogroup`? User `daemon` and group `daemon`? Another?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a new user which has been helpfully named after your service.

This way you can excercise tight controls over its permissions, and also tighter controls over the files managed by your service.

Something like this (say your daemone is called antoniod):

```
useradd -s /sbin/nologin antoniod
```

Then you can chown/chmod your files appropriately (say you have your binaries in /opt/antoniod and data in /var/antoniod-data):

```
  chown -R antoniod:antoniod /opt/antoniod/
  chown -R antoniod:antoniod /var/antoniod-data/
  chmod -R 0550 /opt/antoniod/
  chmod -R 0770 /var/antoniod-data/
```

If you want advice on the startup script itself, look into distro-specific support, e.g. `daemon` function (RedHat) or `stop-start-daemon` (Debian)

HTH